# Is the WebAii test automation framework dead?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

Is the WebAii framework still available and free?  Am I just missing it?

After putting it off for too long, I've finally started automated UI testing on my current project.  I had WebAii from ArtOfTest on my list to look at, but it looks like it's been killed off by Telerik and now they're asking $1500 for their new WebUI test studio.  I can't find anything definitive on Telerik's site, too much marketing.  But, it seems to be pretty clear.

Comment: I'm seeing the older free edition  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760790/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still alive, just a little harder to find:

http://www.telerik.com/products/web-testing-tools/webaii-framework-features.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yep it's still available and it's free. You can find online documentation for it here:
http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has moved around on Telerik's site, so the URLs in earlier posts don't seem to work any more.  But the framework is still there and the software is still available freely (with commercial support available).

- Docs: http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework/getting-started
- Software: http://www.telerik.com/download/testing-framework