# Looking for WebAii Framework free edition online - before the Telerik merge

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface

Art of Test produced a nice UI testing tool for free -- WebAii Framework-- that I've been using to add client-side DOM unit tests to my projects. Recently they merged with Telerik and it's now a commercial product. From free to >$1500 is suddenly very expensive. Does anybody know if the community edition is still available, or if the last free version is available for download? At least I can finish off with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework is still [free and available](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/webaii-framework-features.aspx) (Click Free Download, sign in, and you will be given the option to download the free version). What Telerik (we) are selling is derived from the Design canvas, which was commercial before the merge.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's great news! I couldn't locate this on the Telerik site at the time of posting, but then again I might have not been looking in the proper place. Am bookmarking for future ref.

Comment: Thank you for posting this link. This was the only way I could find it, it seems to be difficult to find on Telerik's site.